# Const Defined in Base Class Not Resolvable in Child Class

Tags: php, propel

For anyone that has read my last couple of questions, I have successfully got CI and Propel integrated and autoloading is working great.  Now I am getting into the nuances of Propel itself.

From my CI controller, I want to query all of the records from a table via Propel.  So the code in my controller is like this:

```
function index() {
    $data = array();
    $data['policytypes'] = PolicytypeQuery::create()->find();
    $this->load->view('policytype_view',$data);
}
```

Somewhere down in the callstack for `PolicytypeQuery::create()->find()`, we step into `ModelCriteria::__construct()`, which yields the following error:

```
constant(): Couldn't find constant Policytype::PEER
```

Here's the entire `__construct()` method:

```
public function __construct($dbName = null, $modelName, $modelAlias = null){
    $this->setDbName($dbName);
    $this->originalDbName = $dbName;
    $this->modelName = $modelName;
    // THIS LINE GENERATES THE ERROR
    $this->modelPeerName = constant($this->modelName . '::PEER');  
    $this->modelAlias = $modelAlias;
    $this->tableMap = Propel::getDatabaseMap($this->getDbName())->getTableByPhpName($this->modelName);
}
```

So the generated **Policytype** class is just a stub, and inherits from **BasePolicytype**, which has a bit more meat to it (but is also generated).  In **BasePolicytype** we have:

```
abstract class BasePolicytype extends BaseObject  implements Persistent
{

    /**
     * Peer class name
     */
    const PEER = 'PolicytypePeer';
```

So...the const is defined in the base class.  ***Why is it not resolvable from the child class?***

---

**UPDATE:**

So, this *does* work:

```
abstract class ClassA {
    const CLASSA_CONST = 'foo';
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
}

class ClassC {
    function __construct($classname){
        echo constant($classname . "::CLASSA_CONST");
    }
}

$c=new ClassC("ClassB");
```

Both run under PHP 5.3.

Comment: Can `ModelCriteria` _really_ see `BasePolicytype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "resolvable" (visible and accessible), but you got the name wrong.

It's `BasePolicytype::PEER`, not `Policytype::PEER`.

Comment: So, based on the code in `ModelCriteria`, are you saying that `ModelCriteria::modelName` should be initialized as "BasePolicytype"?  And, per my question, this is generated code (Propel framework).  So maybe **they** got the name wrong?

Comment: @AJ: Not necessarily; how you go about fixing it robustly depends on the overarching framework and I don't know enough about that to comment. All I can say is that the end result of this code is wrong, and this is why. And I don't really care who wrote it: as far as this SO question's concerned, it's your code. ;)

Comment: Please see my updated question.  I wrote a simple test implementation to mimick the inheritance scenario.  It works differently than the Propel code. The output prints 'foo' (no error generated).  Any additional thoughts?

Comment: @AJ: That's a good testcase (though [this](http://codepad.org/o5KWT4L4) is better); well done! I'll take another look at this. In the meantime, keep adding stuff to your testcase until the problem appears; then you've found the issue.

Comment: OK I updated my test case again...incorporated usage of `constant()` and added ClassC to emulate the role ModelCriteria. The test still works. Continuing to research...going to look at namespaces next.

Comment: The problem **is** namespaces.  When I moved the code to different files, but didn't specify a namespace, it still worked.  As soon as I define a different namespace for ClassC than ClassA and ClassB, I am able to reproduce the error.  So I will be reporting this to Propel as a bug.

Comment: @AJ: Interesting. Do post a link to the bug report if they're public.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the exact same problem described above, however, in my case, the problem was not a bug with Propel.  It was a **class name collision** in my code.

I was adding propel to an existing system.  In my case the collision was a table called "product".  I already have a `class Product` loaded.  So when I try to use propel, it *never auto-loads the propel `Product` class at all*.  Hence, the undefined constant.  It's using the wrong code.

The solution is dependent on your situation. I don't expect this to be a quick transition, and I don't want to refactor the deprecated code, so I'm renaming `Product` in my schema. In a different situation, I might refactor the old code to avoid the collision.

I figured this out reading [this soliloquy](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/propel-users/5m9mE00KkwQ), thanks David Rea.

Comment: I tried generating Propel with namespaces but the generator only puts the namespace in the Base* classes, not the abstracted classes, so the abstracted classes will still conflict with my controllers.